# Offline wallet on Android: can't access the JSON file

Tags: java, android, ethereum

I'm trying to develop an app with Android Studio that creates a wallet file for the Ethereum Blockchain. I'm following this [example](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/an-introduction-to-ethereum-development-on-android-using-web3j-and-infura-763940719997).

I have two problems:

- When I'm testing the app on my physical device, I can track down where is the JSON file, open it and see what is inside. On the Android Studio emulator I cannot find it.
- Either on the emulator or physical device, the `WalletUtils.loadCredentials` function throws an error saying "some_filepath" (is a directory).

Code here:

```
 public void createWallet(View view){
    try{
        WalletUtils.generateNewWalletFile(password, walletDir);
        toastAsync("Wallet generated as" + walletDir);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        toastAsync("ERROR:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void getAddress(View view){
    try {
        Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(password, walletDir.getAbsoluteFile());
        toastAsync("Your address is " + credentials.getAddress());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        toastAsync("ERROR:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I suppose `loadCredentials` can't reach the file, but I don't know why. I'm afraid the emulator actually doesn't create a file, because I couldn't find any, but on my physical device the file is there and `loadCredentials` still throws error

Answer (score 1):

A `File` object in Java can represent both files and directories. I understand that `walletDir` `File` object is pointing to a directory where `createWallet()` method will store your credentials file. Then `getAbsoluteFile()` will return the same directory `File` object. You have to check the documentation on how to get a reference to the credentials file, or the path to it. Maybe `WalletUtils.generateNewWalletFile()` returns this information?